# Extract numeric and non-numeric part from a string with WSO2

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-esb

Thanks before. i want need help. I have simple process flow with wso2. The plan was validate and print string for alphabet and numeric. I can print both of them. but i think the formula was so much affort with that. i want find the simple way. i done try with regular expression. but when i try with that. i always get error result

My code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/split1" name="SplitAlphaNumber" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="//OperationValueRegex/Value" name="Value" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <OperationValueRegex xmlns="">
                        <Result1>$1</Result1>
                        <Result2>$2</Result2>
                    </OperationValueRegex>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="translate(., translate($ctx:Value,'0123456789',''), '')"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="translate(., translate($ctx:Value,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',''), '')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Expected Result was like this

```
<OperationValueRegex>
    <Result1>1234</Result1>
    <Result2>Mario Naga</Result2>
</OperationValueRegex>
```

Sample Input from postman :

```
<OperationValueRegex>
        <Value>Mario Naga 1234</Value>
</OperationValueRegex>
```

and actual output :

```
<OperationValueRegex>
    <Result1>
        1234
</Result1>
    <Result2>
        MarioNaga
</Result2>
</OperationValueRegex>
```

Please need suggestion with this. thanks

Comment: Can you show us the input and the actual output? This would make solving this issue a lot easier. Please add these to the original question and not in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you do a second translate to get rid of leading/trailing spaces. This messes up your values. Instead you can use normalize-space() function as follows, this gets you the desired output:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="SplitAlphaNumber" context="/split1">
   <resource methods="POST">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="Value" expression="//OperationValueRegex/Value" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <OperationValueRegex xmlns="">
                  <Result1>$1</Result1>
                  <Result2>$2</Result2>
               </OperationValueRegex>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="normalize-space(translate($ctx:Value,'0123456789',''))"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="normalize-space(translate($ctx:Value,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',''))"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: can we not set like '0123456789', and 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' on the script. did we have a simple way to filter alphabet and numeric for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler way to achieve what you need. Make sure Xpath 2.0 is enabled in WSO2 Server.

Use the following two XPath expressions.

```xml
fn:tokenize($ctx:Value, ' ')[matches(., '\d+')] // Tokenize the String with space and extract the part with numeric values.

fn:replace($ctx:Value, ' \d+', '') //Replace the numeric part from the string
```

**PLFactory Mediator**

```xml
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <OperationValueRegex xmlns="">
            <Result1>$1</Result1>
            <Result2>$2</Result2>
        </OperationValueRegex>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="fn:tokenize($ctx:Value, ' ')[matches(., '\d+')]" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" />
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="fn:replace($ctx:Value, ' \d+', '')" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" />
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. i was learn new about setting xpath 2.0 on studio. and i want asking once more, if you dont mind. can explain me about what different with tokenize, replace, and matches. and i always get confuse for using like \d or \D. maybe can share the link or the site for me to read what i asking. thanks for the support once again :)

Comment: Nice alternate take. Small sidenote as I dont know what the exact requirements are. The function to extract the numbers will only work if the there is only one number. For example input '1234 5678' will result in 1234. Tokenize combined with matches only gets the first hit it seems.

Comment: Yes, generally tokenizing solutions are tightly coupled with the input format. So you will have to tweak this according to your input. Please read more on Xpath function here https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-tokenize